# Image load event in IE8; event is undefined and this is `window` object

Tags: javascript

I have written the below code and it is working in all modern browsers except in `<IE9`

```
<script>
    function eventH(event) {
        alert(this);
    }
</script>

<img src="h300.png" onload="eventH(arguments[0]);"/>
```

It fires event handler, but `event` is undefined and `this` value is parent object. Why?

Does IE handle this differently or I am wrong somewhere in understanding this?

Comment: What is `arguments[0]` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and below do not implement the W3C event model. For IE, what you need might instead be part of `window.event`.

QuirksMode gives a good set of [examples](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) of how to write event-handling code compatible with both modern browsers and old IE versions.

Also note that when you call a JavaScript function without using dot notation, the global window object is `this` (except in ES5 strict mode, in which accessing `this` is not allowed in this case). Instead, you can pass `this` to your function as an argument.

However, it may be better to just attach your event handler using [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (W3C model) or [.attachEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Microsoft model) instead of specifying it in the HTML. Then, `this` will work as expected.